# Score Sheet using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

I wanted to build a webpage which displays the score of particular people.
It would have 3 columns, namely, rank, name and points.
The rank column is an auto updating column.
I want the database the display the scores and the corresponding ranks in an ascending order way.
I will update the score manually into the database or by using SQL query 'update'. But then by refreshing the webpage the ranks should get sorted according to the points.

I've tried this

```
SELECT * FROM 'SCORE' ORDER BY 'POINTS' ASC;
```

Here, score is the table and points is the column of points.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use single quote around column names. Use backtick instead,

```
SELECT *
FROM `SCORE` 
ORDER BY `POINTS` ASC;
```

Comment: @AyushKhemka wrapping it will single quote converts it to character. so by doing this: `'POINTS'`, its not a column anymore but a normal text.